# CDockablePane and CMFCToolBar on the bottom

Tags: mfc

I managed to get a toolbar on the top if a cdockablepane window but not on the bottom.
Does anyone have a sample of how to do this ?

Tia.

Comment: Why not show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use EnableDocking

```
m_wndTool1AtTop.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY); 
DockPane(&m_wndTool1AtTop); 
m_wndTool2AtBottom.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_BOTTOM); 
DockPane(&m_wndTool2AtBottom);
m_wndTool2AtBottom.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
```